# How to stream camera preview to RTMP server in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, streaming, rtmp

I am developing an app in which the camera preview will be streamed to an nginx RTMP server. My searching ended to 3 things.

1. MSDN sample of [real-time communication](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Simple-Communication-Sample-eac73290). It uses Windows Phone 8.1 APIs & STSP protocol, but I want to do in WP8 with rtmp:// protocol
2. Second thing is [Reelsome](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ad2ad650-4b4f-4c08-9a67-8ff43cf9d32c) app, which does what I want exactly.
3. Third is [RtmpClient library on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RtmpClient/) [(GitHub Link)](https://github.com/mntone/RtmpClient), which supports only receiving from server. My requirement is to send the camera preview to server.

So is there any built in API do stream the current camera preview?

**PS : I don't want to play streaming media but I want to send to server/URL.**

Comment: This is really interesting to me too.

Comment: For me I'm interested in streaming to Wowza server from Windows Phone 8.1.

Comment: Did you get to any interesting point? I'm interested too

Comment: Nops, due to unavailability I need to cancel the project.